# Wordpress hide menu item current page

Tags: wordpress, menuitem

For a client of mine, I need to disable the current page in a sidebar menu.

I attached two pictures. So let's say you have 2 pages (there are more pages though), a "contact" and "about us" page. When you're on the contact page, there's no contact link in the sidebar menu and vice versa. I can't do this by hand because there are like 10 pages for each category.

Thanks in advance,
Pim van Delft

[Menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUG5J.png) [Menu item different page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tz43.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions without code will generally get closed. Screenshots don't tell us anything. That said, if you are using the native WP menu, the current page `li` will have a class like `current-page-item`. Use CSS to set that to `display: none`

Comment: Much appreciated and thanks! I will keep that in mind for future reference. You helped me out a lot though :)